# C# Detect Closing Application

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a taskbar replacement, and I want a button for each running application.

```
public void AddBtn(string name) {
        Button newButton = new Button();
        this.Controls.Add(newButton);
        newButton.Location = new Point(count * 75, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height - 25);
        newButton.Text = name;
        newButton.Name = count.ToString();
        newButton.BringToFront();
        count++;
    }

    private void GetRunning()
    {
        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
        foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.MainWindowTitle)).ToList())
            AddBtn(process.ProcessName);
    }
```

This is what I have so far, it creates a button for each running application. I need to detect if one of the applications close, so I can remove the button that corresponds with it. If you think there is a better way to do it, let me know.

Comment: Sidenote: There are more specific rules deciding whether a window appears on the taskbar or not (your current solution would, for example, even list those typical WinForms windows which have `ShowInTaskbar` set to `false`). S. https://web.archive.org/web/20110123054624/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969325.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off, it would be best to move the code for adding the buttons elsewhere, and only use `GetRunning` to get the currently running processes. Modify it like so:

```
private List<Process> GetRunning()
{
    return Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.MainWindowTitle)).ToList();
}

private void AddButtons()
{
    for (var process in this.GetRunning())
    {
        AddBtn(process.ProcessName);
    }
}
```

Now, regarding your issue, there are two solutions:

### Solution 1: Use events

Create a method, `HandleClosed`, which handles all the operations that need to be done when a process has exited:

```
private void HandleClosed(Process sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Stuff
}
```

Then, you can bind it to the processes' [`Exited`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited(v=vs.110).aspx) event like so:

```
private void BindProcesses()
{
    foreach (var process in this.GetRunning())
    {
        process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        process.Exited += this.HandleClosed;
    }
}
```

Now, whenever one of the processes exits, `HandleClosed` will be called, and the process that closed will be passed to it via `sender`.

### Solution 2: Managing it yourself

Add a private field to your class, `private List<Process> prevProcesses;`.

Then create a new method, `GetClosed`:

```
private List<Process> GetClosed()
{
    var current = GetRunning();
    var result = this.prevProcesses.Except(current);
    this.prevProcesses = current;
    return result.ToList();
}
```

What this method does is it gets the current running processes, then compares that enumeration to `prevProcesses`. The processes that are in `prevProcesses` but aren't in `current` are the ones that have closed. Then, it updates `prevProcesses` with the current enumeration.

Finally, get the initial value for `prevProcesses` in your constructor, or any other method that you use for initialization:

`this.prevProcesses = this.GetRunning();`

Comment: For solution 1, don't you need to add `process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;` to make it work?