# Windows Forms - detecting an external application closing to trigger an event

Tags: c#, .net

I am in need of a solution to trigger code when an external application is closing / closes.

I am unable to use `System.Diagnostics Process.GetProcessByName` to detect if the process is running since it might conflict with an anticheat system. I would need trigger the snippet of code only when the program closes and only then.

Comment: show us what you have so far. Remember, `GetProcessByName` uses the name, but without the `.exe` extension.

Comment: I just mentioned GetProcessByName as a solution that I can't use since it might trigger anti cheat although the program is not of a malicious nature, besides wasting system resources

Comment: You didn't say that in your question. You said "i am unable to use it" meaning you would 
 be using it wrong. `GetProcessByName` works perfectly well. You can't use it because of an unorthodox reason that has nothing to do with the framework.

Comment: My bad on the wording, I'll go ahead and update it so it's a bit more obvious, thank you

Comment: If you can't use the `Process` object at all, you'll have to roll your own. I would start by looking at how the `Process` object works (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs) if that doesn't help, then you are going to start to do some pretty hacky stuff: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2018/Detecting-Windows-NT-2K-process-execution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45536518/c-sharp-detect-closing-application

Comment: "it might trigger anti cheat" ...so you don't know if this is actually problem?

Answer (score 0):

I made a good, event-based implementation.

```
    class Monitor
    {
        public event EventHandler ProgramStarted;
        public event EventHandler ProgramClosed;

        public Monitor(string process)
        {
            string pol = "2";
            if (!process.EndsWith(".exe")) process += ".exe";

            var queryString =
                "SELECT *" +
                "  FROM __InstanceOperationEvent " +
                "WITHIN  " + pol +
                " WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process' " +
                "   AND TargetInstance.Name = '" + process + "'";

            var s = @"\\.\root\CIMV2";
            ManagementEventWatcher watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(s, queryString);
            watcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(OnEventArrived);
            watcher.Start();
        } 
        private void OnEventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.NewEvent.ClassPath.ClassName.Contains("InstanceDeletionEvent"))
            {
                EventHandler handler = ProgramClosed;
                handler?.Invoke(this, e);
            }
            else if (e.NewEvent.ClassPath.ClassName.Contains("InstanceCreationEvent"))
            {
                EventHandler handler = ProgramStarted;
                handler?.Invoke(this, e);
            }

        }
    }
```

To use it, you just create an instance of the class and set up the events. For example:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var mon = new Monitor("chrome");
            mon.ProgramClosed += Mon_ProgramClosed;
            mon.ProgramStarted += Mon_ProgramStarted;
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }

        private static void Mon_ProgramStarted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Program started.");
        }

        private static void Mon_ProgramClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Program closed.");
        }
```

Make sure to add reference to System.Drawing if you're using a console app, and ,for winforms, adjust the modifiers.

Comment: For some reason System.Management doesn't contain ManagementEventWatcher and EvenArrivedEventArgs in my .net  framework 4.7.1 build of this form although the documentation clearly shows them being present 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management?view=netframework-4.7.1

Any ideas?

Comment: @Hazel PLEASE ADD reference to System.Management in the references tab.

Comment: I managed to figure it out, eventho System.Management is apart of the framework, I still needed the nugget package. I also read over the code a bit more in detail and as far as I understand it, it hooks directly to a program which might easily trigger any anticheat software which is what i'm trying to avoid since i do not want to get people banned for no reason. Thank you for the code though, even if I don't have any uses for it right now it's still fairly useful!